# Cooking stove is causing a short circuit, how do I diagnose it further?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, stove

There was a problem that caused my circuit breaker to reset over and over again. I isolated this problem to my cooking stove.

It was connected to the main so that it could generate a spark to ignite the natural gas.

I have disconnected it from the main and anyone has seen a problem like this before? How do I investigate further regarding why it is causing a short circuit?

Thanks

Comment: Does your breaker have GFCI or AFCI capability? Was this recently added?  If it is not a GFCI/AFCI trip, you should not be resetting beakers repeatedly as it can start a fire (or break the  breaker, at which point it will no longer protect you).

Comment: Does your breaker have a TEST button on it?

Comment: @Harper, technically, I was not resetting it repetitively, it has a residual current device (RCD). Thanks for this heads up.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, no, but the RCD has a TEST button on it.

Comment: Where in the world are you? Also, can you get a sensitive (capable of reading in 10 or 1mA increments) current clamp or clampmeter?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: He is in New Zealand, see his profile. AFCI is not mandatory there yet (or if it is, it's not mentioned in Wikipedia yet.)

Comment: @Fizz -- good catch on the profile :) and yeah, NZ uses the IEC 230V system with a central 30mA RCD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visually [inspect the igniters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6eBxARLqjNo). If if you see any cracks in them or burned wires, that's almost certainly the fault to fix.

If you don't see anything wrong with the igniters, check with an ohmmeter if there's short between line and ground on the input plug of of stove. It's not clear to me from your description of the problem if the breaker disconnects when you push the spark/lightning button or all the time... but try to repeat the scenario with the ohmmeter. If there's a fault to ground somewhere, it's almost certainly from a wire with burnt insulation... somewhere inside the stove; you'll have to trace/inspect all the wires.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the breaker was tripping due to a short circuit leading to a high current draw. Another possibility is that the breaker that was tripping is an "arc fault" breaker or a ground fault breaker. Could it be that the igniters on some stoves trip some arc fault breakers?